# How to create a Google doc for every new row added to a Google sheet?

Tags: google-docs

I am looking for a way to create a Google doc for every new row added to a specific Google sheet. I would like the Google doc to be named based on corresponding column values in the Google spreadsheet - i.e., column A=Last Name, column B=First name, column C=employee ID; I would like a Google doc to exist for every entry and to be named in this format: **[Column A] _ [Column B]_[Column C]**

Has anyone done this before, or does anyone have tips on how to set something like this up?

Comment: My first thought is the google command line tool for accessing its cloud services. Might it be possible to pull down the spreadsheet, create a doc if there is a new row, and push the doc back to google? I don't know of a more elegant way.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to run something like this on a time based trigger. This scans the last 20 entries and would create a new document if it hasn't already been created. It isn't instantaneous, but could be run often enough to be effective. Otherwise it would be best to have a form add the data to the sheet and create the new document.

```
function myFunction() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();  
var start = lastRow - 20;
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(start, 1, 21, 4);
var data = dataRange.getValues();
for (i in data){
  if (data[i][4] == 'complete'){
    continue;
  }
  var name = data[i][0]+'_' +data[i][1]+'_'+data[i][2];
  var doc = DocumentApp.create(name);
  //insert code to manipulate document here (unless you want blank documents)
  sheet.getRange(start + i, 3).setValue('complete');
  }
}
```

It is probably a good idea to create a second sheet on this spreadsheet to keep track of the new document ids when you create them. This will save you a lot of time later if you want add data to them later.